# Why can't I create a new table with room migration?

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

The app I'm developing needs to be able to download some "objects" from api to make them available offline, and I'm using Room with sqlite to persist them locally on the device.
For the first table I needed to create I could make it work without any problems and everything worked perfectly.
The problem came when I created a second table, which room Migrations can't create in the database for some reason I couldn't figure out.

I have already tried to recreate the entities, clean up the schemas so that android studio recreates the json files, but without success so far.

Actually the json file with schema is created correctly, but when I try to run the app I get one of the following exceptions:

```
08-06 15:07:18.558 3844-3844/br.com.neoedu.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.neoedu.app, PID: 3844
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle Resposta(br.com.neoedu.objeto.model.Resposta).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Resposta', columns={correta=Column{name='correta', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, questao=Column{name='questao', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, resposta=Column{name='resposta', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, img_resposta=Column{name='img_resposta', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Resposta', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=null}
        at br.com.neoedu.common.dao.AppDatabase_Impl$1.validateMigration(AppDatabase_Impl.java:109)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:87)
```

This is the entity whose room cannot create the table and following the schema json.

````
@Entity
public class Resposta implements RequestModel, Serializable {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("questao")
    @Ignore
    private Objeto questao;

    @ColumnInfo(name="questao")
    private int idQuestao;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("resposta")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "resposta")
    private String resposta;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("correta")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "correta")
    private boolean correta;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("imgResposta")
    @ColumnInfo(name= "img_resposta")
    private String imgResposta;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Objeto getQuestao() {
        return questao;
    }

    public void setQuestao(Objeto questao) {
        this.questao = questao;
    }

    public String getResposta() {
        return resposta;
    }

    public void setResposta(String resposta) {
        this.resposta = resposta;
    }

    public boolean isCorreta() {
        return correta;
    }

    public void setCorreta(boolean correta) {
        this.correta = correta;
    }

    public String getImgResposta() {
        return imgResposta;
    }

    public void setImgResposta(String imgResposta) {
        this.imgResposta = imgResposta;
    }

    public int getIdQuestao() {
        return idQuestao;
    }

    public void setIdQuestao(int idQuestao) {
        this.idQuestao = idQuestao;
    }```


Schema: 

```{
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "database": {
    "version": 2,
    "identityHash": "95d9e6cab68a655a3f82759ed5975ac3",
    "entities": [
      {
        "tableName": "Objeto",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `tipo` TEXT, `tipo_questao` INTEGER NOT NULL, `tri` TEXT, `titulo` TEXT, `descricao` TEXT, `conteudo` TEXT, `tipoConteudo` TEXT, `status` INTEGER NOT NULL, `link` TEXT, `fonte` TEXT, `data_criacao` INTEGER, `revisado_em` INTEGER, `exame` TEXT, `sub_exame` TEXT, `periodo_exame` TEXT, `ano` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "id",
            "columnName": "id",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "tipo",
            "columnName": "tipo",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "tipoQuestao",
            "columnName": "tipo_questao",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "tri",
            "columnName": "tri",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "titulo",
            "columnName": "titulo",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "descricao",
            "columnName": "descricao",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "conteudo",
            "columnName": "conteudo",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "tipoConteudo",
            "columnName": "tipoConteudo",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "status",
            "columnName": "status",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "link",
            "columnName": "link",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "fonte",
            "columnName": "fonte",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "dataCriacao",
            "columnName": "data_criacao",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "revisadoEm",
            "columnName": "revisado_em",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "exame",
            "columnName": "exame",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "subExame",
            "columnName": "sub_exame",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "periodoExame",
            "columnName": "periodo_exame",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "ano",
            "columnName": "ano",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          }
        ],
        "primaryKey": {
          "columnNames": [
            "id"
          ],
          "autoGenerate": false
        },
        "indices": [],
        "foreignKeys": []
      },
      {
        "tableName": "Resposta",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `questao` INTEGER NOT NULL, `resposta` TEXT, `correta` INTEGER NOT NULL, `img_resposta` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "id",
            "columnName": "id",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "idQuestao",
            "columnName": "questao",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "resposta",
            "columnName": "resposta",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "correta",
            "columnName": "correta",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "imgResposta",
            "columnName": "img_resposta",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": false
          }
        ],
        "primaryKey": {
          "columnNames": [
            "id"
          ],
          "autoGenerate": false
        },
        "indices": [],
        "foreignKeys": []
      }
    ],
    "setupQueries": [
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)",
      "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, \"95d9e6cab68a655a3f82759ed5975ac3\")"
    ]
  }
}
````

Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Objeto.class, Resposta.class}, version = 2)
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class, QuestaoConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "neoedu.db";
    private static volatile AppDatabase instance;

    //private AppDatabase(){}

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
        }
    };

    public synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if(null == instance) {
            instance = create(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static AppDatabase create(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                DB_NAME
            )
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }


    public abstract ObjetoDAO getObjetoDao();
    public abstract RespostaDAO getRespostaDao();
}
```

what am i missing?

Comment: In your `MIGRATRION_1_2` you need to add this newly created table, simply copy * paste the `CREATE TABLE` statement in the JSON schema file. You need to write a migration that creates your 2nd table since Room will just be opening and not creating new tables for an user of your application with an existing database.

Comment: Lol, really? To be honest, I had thought of doing that, but I thought it would be a bit redundant. I had understood that this json would be enough for Room to understand that it would need to create the new table, but living and learning, as I am new to the Android world I still have a long way to go ... Thanks!

Comment: I agree it is a bit redundant, maybe one day those migrations will be auto-generated. :)